# Pre fetching Images using Glide in android

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an activity which will loads images one by one in same imageview using fadein fadeout animations. In order to provide a good user experience i want to pre fetch the images asynchronously and show them with a constant flow. I want to use glide for achieving the above said behaviour. But i am confused because there are two different approaches I found on internet to pre fetch (Cache) images. First is using Glide's *.preload()* method:

```
Glide.with(this)
.load(url)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
.preload()
```

Second is using Glide's *.downloadOnly(int , int)* method:

```
Glide.with(applicationContext)
.load(yourUrl)
.downloadOnly(500, 500);
```

I have two questions:

1. What is difference between `preload` and `downloadOnly` and which one best suites my situation?
2. How to know that all of my images have been pre fetched and i can continue the process of showing images using one of the above (Best one) approaches?

Answer (score 2):

See the Glide Documentation here :

[Glide Documentation](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/380/index.html)

Search for class "DrawableTypeRequest" which has both these methods preload() and downloadOnly().

As the documentation says :

**preload()**

> Preloads the resource into the cache using Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL as the > target width and height. Equivalent to calling preload(int, int) with > > Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL as the width and height.

**downloadOnly(int width, int height)**

> Loads the original unmodified data into the cache and returns a Future > that can be used to retrieve the cache File containing the data.

I would suggest preload() would be fine for you.